# Is it possible to have a different indentation (tab size) per project in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to change indentation (tab size), and currently I automatically change the indentation  according to the file, e.g. when the default size is 2 but the file size is 4 VSCode automatically uses 4 in that file.

Currently I'm using indentation 2 spaces as default. However, I'm working in two projects at the moment, one that uses 4 and another that uses 2 and every time I create a new file VSCode defaults to 2 regardless of the project I'm in. I would like VSCode to adjust the indentation  project-wide and not per file.

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried changing it in the "Workspace" tab (as opposed to the "User" tab?).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that and as soon as I create a new file within the project it defaults back to 2 spaces.

Comment: It seems to work for me. Perhaps you have something else that's overriding this setting (not really sure what it could be, sorry).

Comment: You are right! I think I was changing both at the same time, it works per workspace now.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the extension "EditorConfig for VSCode" (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EditorConfig.EditorConfig). Then you create and maintain project specific .editorconfig files (https://editorconfig.org/), for example

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 4
```